# Find the minimum sum of elements in a 2D array of n*3 dimension such that index selected from a row shouldn't be selected in adjacent rows

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a n*3 2D Array and need to find the min. sum of elements such that:

1. No rows can be missed out i.e. there should be an element from each row.
2. Only one element can be selected from a row.
3. Element selected in a row can't be selected in adjacent rows.

eg.
10 50 45
30 10 15 
70 05 25
09 27 97

- If 10 is selected from row at index 0, 30 can't be selected from row at index 1.
- Similarly, if 10 is selected from row at index 1, 05 can't be selected from row at index 2.

The optimal solution for the array is: 10+15+05+9 = 39

**Note:** Maybe an iteration of Hungarian Algorithm may work for this.

But I don't know how to go with it.

Comment: I do not understand the example, according to rule 3 you cannot select 9 in row 4 because you already selected 10 in row 1, right? If your matrix was 3x3, then Hungarian method is exactly the algorithm to use here.

Comment: @SaiBot: row 4 is nor adjacent to row 1, so rule 3 is not applicable here.

Comment: Where is the bipartit graph you want to perform the Hungarian Algorithm on?

Comment: Ah i see, did not read rule 3 precisely. The matrix represents a bipartite graph. Each row and each column is a node, and the entries represent the edge cost between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic Programming.

Let `DP[i][j]` be the minimum sum in the first `i` rows and the last taken element was from column `j`.

Assuming the array is 1-indexed

```
DP[0][j] = 0

DP[i][j] = min(DP[i-1][x])+A[i][j]  (j!=x , 1<=x<=3)
```

Answer is `min(DP[N][j])`; the minimum is over `1<=j<=3`.

**Edit:**

```
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            int mn=INF;
            for (int x=1;x<=3;x++)
                if (j!=x) // 3rd rule
                    mn = min(mn,DP[i-1][x]);
            DP[i][j] = mn+A[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<min(DP[n][1],min(DP[n][2],DP[n][3]))<<endl;
```

Comment: What does 'x' signify here ?

Comment: You check all 1<=x<=3 such that x!=j,  ill update the answer with more details

Comment: It might be not easy to check the constrains, because your choices are not independent.

Comment: @mrSmith42 what do you mean? the first two constraints are obviously met. And my choices are not independent, the column I chose in the last row cannot be chosen in the next row, which is guaranteed in the method I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

If no clever problem specific idea comes up,

I would go with a [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)  and cut of the the branch as soon as one of the constraints is violated.

---

**P.s.** Since you can estimate the worst possible value, you could use [**A*-search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which will most likely speed it up.

Comment: Yeah, that's ok but complexity would be O(n!)

Comment: Isn't it O(2^n)? since you will always have two options in the next row.

Comment: If you have `m` rows it should be **O((3*n)^m)** since you use one element of each row.